# How can I give the UHD: USRP Source a command to change the center frequency after some samples?

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp

I need to send some data from a file by a frequency hopping USRP sink and receive by the USRP source. Both have to change the frequency synchronously and constantly after an amount of samples. How can I tell (especially) the USRP source in the python code to change the frequency?

https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/page_uhd.html
the UHD Source and Sink has an command port.

```c
pmt::pmt_t command = pmt::cons( // Make a pair

    pmt::mp("freq"), // Key is 'freq' => sets the frequency
    pmt::mp(1.1e9) // Set the frequency to 1.1 GHz
);

// Now pass 'command' into the USRP block's command port
```

Sounds like a way to change it. But I don understand how I'll connect this to the USRP? And how to trigger it after an amount of samples.
Does anybody has an example or suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to create a timed command to make the commands synchronuous:

https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/page_uhd.html

Create a `tune_request` object and then the `time` command with a timestamp when it is to be executed on the USRP. Send the `tune` command with the `tune_request` object. Finish with `time` command and parameter `PMT_NIL`.

If the message is constant you could to a **Message Strobe** block. If the parameters change (like the center frequency), you need to use Python. Before creating your OOT module, you could consider the **Python Block** element in GRC which allows you to create these messages in python from within GRC.